# Microsoft office verify add-in loaded

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-addin, office-addins

We developed a COM add-in for microsoft office.
We would like to make sure that our add-in is loaded when the office application starts (meaning that no one tried to disable it in the registry).
Our current solution is that We are using an external application with which the add-in is suppose to communicate after specific time, counting from the second the office application started. If it didn't communicate, then we stop the office application, verify in the registry that we are suppose to load, and start it again.
This is a problematic system because no one can guess what is a suitable time to wait, and you don't want to give the user after 10 minutes of work, suddenly an error, not to mention that it is important for us that the add-in will beloaded as soon as possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a dirty solution but you can wait until the title of the main Outlook window changes from "Opening Outlook" to something else?

[image: Outlook in the Task Manager.]

The screen shot above is cropped from a screenshot I took while Outlook was still loading on my machine.

So maybe poll the processes for Outlook, get it's main window caption and see if it contains Opening.
Very dirty solution that may have 2 flaws:

1. Localized Outlook may show a different message.
2. You may miss the Opening message depending on how much does it take to query the processes, get the main window and what is your timer interval.

I think after the "Opening" message goes away - all Add-Ins should have been loaded provided they are not disabled.

Maybe the MainWindowTitle property of the Outlook process will be the one to inspect for the "Opening message". Haven't tried yet:

[Process.MainWindowTitle Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx)

Update:
This will hopefully workaround the scenario that Outlook is doing some Data Integrity checks or things like that during the startup prior firing the existing Add-Ins, but you should really do a lot of testing before considering this approach safe ...

Hope this helps, let us know if it works so we can use it as well in case we need it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is really what your "guardian" application is doing, you may want to reconsider the approach.
1. Why do you want to stop office app before checking the registry?
2. What do you do if your check has passed but the add-in is still not running?

I would suggest something like:
1. If this is so important to have the add-in running, replace office app shortcut with your app (if you can, e.g. corporate environment)
2. Check registry *before* you close office app so you can do it without waiting at all
3. Try emulating office app inside your "guradian" app - create instance and check if add-in is loaded

With any approach, this sounds like either a corporate rule enforcement, in which case you have control over shortcuts and office app installation, or an overly imposing commercial software, in this case - think (i.e. is that the right approach).

HTH